# How do I make this test pass?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to test the return type on `__repr__`. It's not a string so what is it? What's happening here?

```
import unittest
class MyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    class Dog(object):
            def __init__(self, initial_name):
                self._name = initial_name

            def get_self(self):
                return self

            def __repr__(self):
                return "Dog named '" + self._name + "'"

    def runTest(self):
        fido = self.Dog("Fido")
        self.assertEqual("Dog named 'Fido'", fido.get_self()) #Fails!

test=MyClass("runTest")
runner=unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(test)
```

Running this gives:

```
FAIL: runTest (__main__.MyClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/xxxxx/fido.py", line 15, in runTest
     self.assertEqual("Dog named 'Fido'", fido.get_self())
   AssertionError: "Dog named 'Fido'" != Dog named 'Fido'

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Ran 1 test in 0.006s

 FAILED (failures=1)
```

How can I get this test to pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self.assertEqual("Dog named 'Fido'", repr(fido.get_self()))
```

or just

```
self.assertEqual("Dog named 'Fido'", repr(fido))
```

Otherwise `assertEqual` is correctly telling you that the string is not equal to the object. When it renders the error message it uses `repr` on the object, so the error looks a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

repr return a string, but fido.get_self() return a Dog object, not a string.

When there is an assertion error, it uses "repr" to display a readable representation of your Dog instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of the comparison your assert does by doing `print type(s)`. You are comparing `__repr__` with `str`. To make it work compare both strings. See [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)